# how to get the value of checkboxs that checked using Django framework.?

Tags: python, ajax, django

How to get the value of checkboxs that checked and send it to views this is my form !

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"method="POST" action="{% url 'paperCustomization_submission'%}">


                   <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                       {%for question_type in questions_type%}
                         <div class="checkbox" id="checkbox-question" >
                                    <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" id="question_type_id" value="{{question_type.question_type}}" onclick="function1();"class="flat" name="checkbox_question"> {{question_type.question_type}}
                                    </label>

                                </div>
                                {%endfor%}
                              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the name field in the checkbox input. simply add the name field and get the field by name in simple post method in Django as below.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    isChecked = request.POST.get('checkbox_question')
```

For checked checkbox you can add Below Jquery code.

```
$(document).on('change','input.flat', function() {
    $('input.flat').not(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the checkbox input using the ***name*** attribute of ***inside*** tag

HTML Code will be like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="questions" value={{question_type.question_type}} onchange="pushToArray()"/>
```

and add this Javascript code inside the head tag

```
<script>
var questions = []
        function pushToArray(event)
            {
              questions.push(event.value);
                return;
            }
</script>
```

where 'questions' is the parameter you want as the input from checkbox and you can parse the request to get these questions as

```
questions = request.POST.get('questions')
```